# Sliping the laplacian in the sense of distributions

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $B(r)$ designate the open ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, centered at the origin, $f$ a $C^{\infty}$ and $\phi$ a test function with compact support in $B(R)$. If I take the integral of $f\Delta \phi$ on $B(R)\setminus B(r)$, ($0<r<R$),  can I steel slip the laplacina over $f$, i.e., 
$$\int_{B(R)\setminus B(r)}f(x)\Delta\phi(x)dx=\int_{B(R)\setminus B(r)}\Delta f(x)\phi(x)dx?$$
It seems to me that the answer should be no, because the derivatives of these functions on the boundary of $B(r)$ are not zero and so Green's identity (theorem) doesn't work as we wished. But is there a trick somewhere to make it work?? I badly need it!!!

Comment: Integration by parts gives $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) \Delta \phi(x)dx =\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Delta  f(x) \phi(x)dx$ but it works only because the boundary terms vanish at $\infty$, not the case for $\int_\Omega$ (those boundary terms are more or less equivalent to Green's theorem)

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\begin{align}
f\nabla^2\phi&=\nabla \cdot (f \nabla\phi)-\nabla f \cdot \nabla \phi\\\\
&=\nabla\cdot(f \nabla\phi-\phi\nabla f)+\phi\nabla^2 f
\end{align}$$

The integral of the divergence term leads to a boundary integral term over $B(r)$ and $B(R)$.

Finally, let $r\to 0$ and $R\to \infty$.

Comment: But $f$ and $\phi$ are not necessary 0 on the boundary of $B(r)$, and the divergence term doesn't  disappear, correct?

Comment: They are not $0$, and the boundary integral is not in general $0$.  But as $r\to 0$, the boundary integral over $B(r)$ approaches zero.

Comment: But $r$ and $R$ are fixed. I cannot make $r$ approach 0.

Comment: Then there is, in general, a non-zero contribution from the boundary integration over $B(r)$.  Since $\phi$ has compact support in $B(R)$, the boundary integral over $B(R)$ is zero.